# Solr Admin Page Shows No Information

Tags: solr, solr4

I'm in the process of trying to get Solr running for my company. I've installed 4.10.3 on a server and have indexed the example docs that come with the zip file. When I start Jetty and go to *localhost:8983* in the browser I see the admin screen as expected. But when I use the server's full name instead of localhost, I get the following result:

[image: Blank admin page]

The information panel is completely empty, while using the *localhost* URL shows the expected graphs and information. I'm running a Win 2008 R2 server. What is preventing me from seeing this information?

The next step is to then try connecting to the same implementation from a client computer using the server's URL, but I have a feeling I need to get this straight before I get to that step.

Comment: Do the logs say anything?

Comment: What happens when you ping the [servername]:solrport? I haven't used SOLR on windows machines much but can u check if the hosts file on your windows has the correct information ?

Comment: It was a firewall issue @jay. Once we opened the port I was able to get what I was looking for. Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction.